# Manually managing photos and storing them in OneDrive

Tags: onedrive, photos

Although I use the sync application to sync music, I don't sync my photos.  Instead, I move my photos off my phone manually (in the same way that you would off a normal digital camera).  I'm taking advantage of my 15 gb of OneDrive space to store my photos.   However, in my phone's photos, it shows each of the folders from my OneDrive which contains pictures.

- When I enter these folders (on the phone), all the pictures from that folder seem to be there; are they just a symbolic link, or have they been downloaded to my phone. If the latter, does this only happen over wifi?
- is there a way to prevent these folders showing the photos app? I *know* where I store photos, I don't need the photos app to tell me - if this is possible it would also serve as an  immediate visual cue as to which photos I haven't taken off my phone yet!

Answer (score 1):

1. Photos stored on Onedrive folders are not downloaded on your phone. They are available only when you turn on your connection (just try and see); they **can** be downloaded, but they won't unless you click on "Save to phone".
2. I'm afraid you can't turn off the Onedrive folder visualization; however, if your problem concerns to photos showing in the main view of the Photos app, you can set the app to show only photos you've tagged as *Favorites*.

Comment: Thanks; so, out of interest, when I go to Photos > Albums, the folders which are listed as being `from SkyDrive` show photos in them - are these photos thumbnail links, or the actual photos in full resolution? When do these get 'synced' - only over WiFi or whenever I have a data connection?

Comment: They are photos in full resolution. They are not *saved* on your phone memory, but when you open them, the image is streamed to your phone. So, if you want to view/save the photo, you can with every type of connection. This implies that if you use a mobile connection, fees will be applied (but I assume that you have a data plan). Else, there won't be any data consumption. I don't know whether there are some settings to manage this things, I'll check out later (and edit the main answer).